# wp_list_pages - is there a way to shorten title for display in footer on smaller screens for specific pages

Tags: wordpress, media-queries, footer, sitemap, page-title

I have a wordpress site, and I am using the wp_list_pages in my footer (as an automated sitemap list) as follows:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;"><?php wp_list_pages('exclude=143,1040,1045,1048&title_li='); ?></ul>
```

On a couple pages I have longer titles. This works fine for larger sized screens, but not so good on smaller screen sizes (too much line wrapping).

Is there a way I can code to check for specific page ids to take advantage of the @media Media Queries, and change the title for smaller screen sizes?

I've seen someone doing something like this to change a title for some pages to be 'Poetry':

```
    <?php wp_list_pages( array(
    'include'  => array( 5, 9, 23 ),
    'title_li' => '<h2>' . __('Poetry') . '</h2>'
    ); ?>
```

, but I wouldn't know how to adjust it to allow the rest of the pages to display with their normal titles, and only use the media query code to change to shorter titles on specific pages for specific sized screens.

Is this even possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is Responsive Web Design. Using specific styles for showing/hiding elements based on screen size is possible using Responsive Web Design which will accomplish what you're looking to do.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en

You can then output the text you want for each target screen size, then show/hide the appropriate HTML element.

You can also take a look at the bootstrap CSS framework to get an idea of what you can accomplish with a robust set of responsive CSS classes and breakpoints.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Yes - that's correct. I create my own wordpress responsive templates, and use media queries frequently in my CSS.  What I can figure out is how to use the wp_list_pages feature which auto creates a page list for me - which I use in my footer as a mini site-map.  Because it is the footer, I have space constraints in the columns, It works OK, just wraps more than I would prefer.. hence the desire to add code to the wp_list_pages function so I can dynamically change the title of specific pages inside that function.

Comment: I would just copy the wp_list_pages function (in /wp-includes/post-template.php) and paste it into your template's functions for as many as you need, i.e. wp_list_pages_mobile, wp_list_pages_desktop, etc. Then you can modify each to render the specific responsive classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to display the trimmed text based on browser width but some JS will be required in that ..

Let me go step by step.

1. Print the subpages and provide and ID to ul (put your required arguments in wp_list_pages function)

   ```
   <?php
   $children = wp_list_pages( 'echo=0' );
   if ( $children) : ?>
       <ul id="subpages">
           <?php echo $children; ?>
       </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
2. At the footer of the page write a jquery to print 2 span tag inside each `<a>` tag of the `<li>`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
               $('#subpages li a').each(function(){
           var org_text = $(this).html();

           var trimed_text = '';
           if(org_text.length > 8){
               trimed_text = org_text.substr(0, 8)+'...';
           } else{
               trimed_text = org_text;
           }
           $(this).html('<span class="trimmed">'+trimed_text+'</span><span class="original">'+org_text+'</span>');
         });
       });
       </script>
   ```

   This will put 2 `<span>` tags inside each `<a>`. For Eg : If your page name is  "Sample Page" then `<span class="trimmed">Sample P...</span><span class="original">Sample Page</span>` . One span containing `class="trimmed"` class and other one containing `class="original"`.
3. Now by use of CSS media query you can display none block these span tags by their class names

   ```
   @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
       .trimmed {
           display : block;
       }
       .original {
           display : none;
       }

   }
   ```

As I am not a CSS guy, so put the media query correctly.
But this can be made to work according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Prakash.  I can see how this solution will work for me.  I have added the PHP you provided inside of my previous UL tag.  And I have created a trimtitle.js script, and have added the wp_enqueue_script( 'trimtitle_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/trimtitle.js', array('jquery'), '', true ); to the function.php page.  When I view source,  I can see the link to the trimtitle.js script, and can click on it, so I know it is being loaded.  However, the resulting code for the mini sitemap doesn't show the span tags, so something is wrong.

Comment: I think I may need to use the $ substitution for wordpress jquery scripts.  But I can't figure out how to do that to the script you provided.  Can you help?  ~  For example, I have another script that is written like this: jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ ) {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
  });
});  ~  So I think I need to do something similar to your script?

Comment: I have updated the above code under <script> tag .. by using $ instead of jQuery. Please try that code

Comment: Prakash: I made the changes to the script (the code is inside a .js file called in via function.php, so the .js file itself doesn't have the script tags inside of it.), but it still doesn't work.  The php code for the sitemap in footer.php works perfectly.  The mini sitemap displays as it should.  It just doesn't seem to execute the script. (Even though I can see the script being pulled in via source code).  Note: I haven't added any CSS media query code yet, so if the script was working, the source code for the sitemap should actually be showing two span classes, and it doesn't.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure that your script is loaded in footer and .. in console there are no errors .